# Как взять get ajax

Tags: php, ajax

Подскажите пожалуйста, есть код:

```
 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url:"/autocomplete/autocomplete.php",
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {'choose' : $(this).val()},
    success: function(res){
        console.log(res);
        var content = '';
        $.each(res, function(i, item){

            content += "<div class='ott' data-id='"+res[i].id+"'>"+res[i].name+" "+res[i].lastname+" "+res[i].lastname+"</div>";
        });
        $('.aut_cont').html('');
        $('.aut_cont').append(content);
    }

});
```

Как к

```
url:"/autocomplete/autocomplete.php"
```

добавить `get id=`, чтобы получилось так:

```
url:"/autocomplete/autocomplete.php?id=взять id со страницы на которой работает данный код"
```

Спасибо.

Comment: `url:"/autocomplete/autocomplete.php?id=<?=$id?>",`

Comment: @u_mulder Спасибо помогло. Давайте ответ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`HTML
<a href="/autocomplete/autocomplete.php?id=<?=$id?>" class="autocomplete-link">Link</a>`

```
var url = $('.autocomplete-link').attr('href');

$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url:url,
   dataType: 'json',
   data: {'choose' : $(this).val()},
   success: function(res){
      console.log(res);
      var content = '';
      $.each(res, function(i, item){

        content += "<div class='ott' data-id='"+res[i].id+"'>"+res[i].name+" "+res[i].lastname+" "+res[i].lastname+"</div>";
    });
    $('.aut_cont').html('');
    $('.aut_cont').append(content);
  }

});
```

если коротко, код не проверял